# chkdsk stopped before it's done?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, chkdsk

[image]

I ran 'chkdsk /r' command on command prompt on my Windows 7 64-bit.

As in the picture, the process finished while it says '10 percent complete'.
I think it took about 8~10 hours.

It's a 2 TB Western Digital external desktop HDD (non-portalble, with power) and it is 445GB free among 1.81 TB.

Is this normal, or did it finish before it's done?

Comment: That's not normal; it should have finished with a message like "Windows checked the file system and found no problems" or "Windows has made corrections to the file system" or "Windows has finished checking your disk." Is there anything interesting in the System event log?

Comment: My guess is that its just an aberration in the program output. Chkdsk tries to update the percentage complete on its original line by skipping back and updating the numbers at the beginning of the current line (this is common with console based UIs). In this case however, because the index check caused error output to be written to the console, the line was advanced, so the console would be updating the percentage complete in a previous line, which may have even scrolled off the page already. So instead, it just prints a new percent complete line, and increments it, until its finally complete.

Comment: CONT. So to sum up, no I don't believe it is the result of a problem at all, just a UI that tries to output info that's tricky to display in a console. The line that says "4131846 Index entries Processed" was the new percent complete line, and changed its message after hitting 100% (chkdsk does that after completing each phase). then it printed the "Index verification completed" message. If in doubt check your SMART stats (its always a good idea to know where those stand) and run the chkdsk. It is likely that now that those indexes are clean, its output will be normal. I think you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

The checkdisk did finish - if you look, there was additional output after the "10%" line - ie a corruption was found at about the 10% mark which was correct.

Its entirely probable that the indexes were quite corrupt and it took a long time to rebuild - a figure of 10 hours is not unrealistic, but you should do some checks to make sure the hard drive is not failing (a good first step is to check the S.M.A.R.T status) - particularly if you did not have a power cut or other unexpected event which you know caused the corruption.

Comment: I think its less that the indexes took some time, but that log messages pushed the display down, orphaning the old percent complete line, so those are just frozen moments in time stuck in the display. thats why there are two of them (well three, since one counted from 11-99% and then changed to the completion message). It didn't actually stop at 10%.